# Write to text file from array list c++

Tags: visual-c++

I have a file with 10 integers. I read the file and put it into a list. I then modify the list (add, delete, etc) and now I want to be able to save that list. So I have no idea how to take the items from my array list and save it into the file.

1) Read the file and put it into list:

```
ifstream intFile, floatFile;
ofstream intFileOut, floatFileOut;

SortedList<int> intList;
SortedList<float> floatList;
int a=0;
float b=0;

intFile.open("int.dat");                            
floatFile.open("float.dat");    

while(intFile>>a)
{
    intList.InsertItem(a);
    a++;
}

while(floatFile >>b)
{
    floatList.InsertItem(b);
    b++;
}

intFile.close();    
floatFile.close();
```

2) Modified the list

```
cout<<"------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"INT LIST: "<<endl;
cout<<"Adding 1 to list..."<<endl;
intList.InsertItem(1);
cout<<"Adding 2 to list..."<<endl;
intList.InsertItem(2);
cout<<"Deleting int 20 from the list..."<<endl;
intList.DeleteItem(20);
cout<<"------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"INTs in the list: "<<endl;
intList.GetNextItem(a);
cout<<"------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"Retriving int 30..."<<endl;
cout<<"Position of int 30: ";intList.RetrieveItem(30);cout<<endl;
```

3) Now I want to take the intList and save it to intFileOut, if that makes sense?

Any tips/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Btw, according to MSDN, SortedList either takes 2 template parameters (System.Collections.Generic) or none at all (System.Collections).

Comment: Also I would use `fstream` (read & write) instead of separate `ifstream` and `ofstream` objects.

Comment: Also `a++` and `b++` seems unnecessary.

Comment: ifstream and ofstream is the way the teacher wanted us to do it and im still getting used to reading and writing file. I just made another file to save the file. It works perfectly and thanks for the suggestion for fstream. I will look into it more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?
(I don't have visual C++ installed nor am I familiar with its special quirks)

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < intList.Count; i++)
{
    intFileOut << intList.GetByIndex(i) << endl;
}
```

Comment: I used something similar to your suggestion but just made a saveFile function and it works the same way. Just outputs all of the items into the new file I created. Thank you for the help.